# Issue with WorksheetFunction.Match in VBA Excel

Tags: vba

I need help please to find another technique instead of "WorksheetFunction.Match" because I'm getting this error:
Run-time error'1004'
Unable to get the match property of the WorkSheetFunction class

the problem is in this code "  iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0) "

Thank you,

Sub SearchData()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim shDatabase As Worksheet ' Database sheet
Dim shSearchData As Worksheet 'SearchData sheet

Dim iColumn As Integer 'To hold the selected column number in Database sheet
Dim iDatabaseRow As Long 'To store the last non-blank row number available in Database sheet
Dim iSearchRow As Long 'To hold the last non-blank row number available in SearachData sheet

Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
Dim sValue As String 'To hold the search text value


Set shDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")


iDatabaseRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


sColumn = frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value

sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value


iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0)

'Remove filter from Database worksheet

If shDatabase.FilterMode = True Then

    shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False

End If

'Apply filter on Database worksheet

If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Project Number" Then

    shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue

Else

    shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"

End If

If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Customer" Then

    shDatabase.Range("B1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue

Else

    shDatabase.Range("B1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"

End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shDatabase.Range("B:B")) >= 2 Then

    'Code to remove the previous data from SearchData worksheet

    shSearchData.Cells.Clear

    shDatabase.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("A1")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 21

    frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "25, 70, 50, 50, 70, 50, 30, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 90, 50, 90"

    If iSearchRow > 1 Then

        frmForm.lstDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!A2:T" & iSearchRow

        MsgBox "Records found."

    End If


Else

   MsgBox "No record found."

End If

shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Then it is not finding `sColumn` in `shDatabase.Range("A1:U1")`  double check if the value truly in the row.  Check that there are not spaces or other characters that do not match.

Comment: You can change `Dim iColumn As Variant`  and `iColumn = Application.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0)` then test whether it is an error or not `If IsError(iColumn) Then` and if true skip the everything as the value was not found.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner for your help.
now it's error in her
shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"

Comment: new questions get new posts.